# Mount and automount and security problems

Tags: security, mount, automounting

Are there any security problems related with (auto)mounting device?

Answer (score 2):

That differs from your setup.

On a private setup (you are accessing your own box) there is no problem. On a company setup (many people are accessing many different boxes from your employer) there are security risks. Just think about USB drives, SD-cards and so on.

For any further answer we need a bit more information.